# Android. Mock Context: java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub

Tags: android, unit-testing

I want to write unit test for my method "getAge" that use android Context.

**StringUtil**

```
public static String getAge(Context context, int age) {
    String result = "";
    result = context.getString(R.string.years_5);
    return result;
}
```

I write my unit test:

**StringUtilTest**

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class StringUtilTest {

@Mock Context mMockContext;

@Test
public void testGetAge() {
    int ageTest = 5;
    assertThat(StringUtil.getAge(mMockContext, ageTest), is(mMockContext.getString(R.string.years_5)));
}
```

But when start test I get error:

java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!

```
at android.content.Context.getString(Context.java:14)
at my.company.StringUtil.getAge(StringUtil.java:49)
at my.company.StringUtilTest.testGetAge(StringUtilTest.java:39)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

Comment: Try using Robolectric: http://robolectric.org/